# Java When I run this method in my code, sometimes it shows full result, other times it doesn't

Tags: java, function, console

If this function is running:

```
public static void maximizeweight(int[] weight, int[] A){
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(A.length);
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            while(totalweight(weight,A) < 630){
                if(A[random]==0)
                    A[random] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

The output some times breaks a bit or freezes eclipse, totally at random, and sometimes it is able to give the whole result, other times it doesn't show the last part of the desired result.

Comment: What does `totalweight(...)` do? You really should do some debugging with a debugger first.

Comment: Most likely due to an infinite loop inside of the method. Please show the entire class, or the _totalweight_ method. Thanks!

Comment: obviously dead loop is possible

Comment: if A[random] != 0 and totalweight < 630 the while loop never ends..I think this is the problem

Comment: Move the `while` loop outside of the for-loop ;)

Comment: <code>public static int totalweight(int[] weight, int[] a){ int totalweight = 0; for (int i=0; i< a.length; i++){ if(a[i]==1) totalweight = totalweight + weight[i]; } //System.out.println("Total weight is: " + totalweight); return totalweight; }</code>

Comment: In the future, please post this not as a comment, but as part of the question itself. This information is much too important to be buried in comments, and was critical to getting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `A[random] != 0` and still your `totalweight()` returns < 630, the while loop would be infinite. One possible fix (and the one I think you need) is to move your `int random = r.nextInt(A.length);` inside your while loop.

```
public static void maximizeweight(int[] weight, int[] A){
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            while(totalweight(weight,A) < 630){
                int random = r.nextInt(A.length);
                if(A[random]==0)
                    A[random] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This would still loop infinitely if the sum of `weight` array is still < 630. So you will need additional checks.